Error: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out. at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.<ConnectAudioAsync>d349.MoveNext()
im trying to make a bot with discord.net and im getting the error Error
when i try to play an audio : System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
at Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuild.d349.MoveNext()
this is my code

        public async Task<bool> ExecuteCommand(SocketMessage message, string cmd, string[] args)
        {
            // Check if command is on cooldown
            if (_cooldowns.ContainsKey(cmd))
            {
                var cooldownEnd = _cooldowns[cmd].AddSeconds(_commandCooldowns[cmd]);
                if (DateTime.UtcNow < cooldownEnd)
                {
                    await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Command \"{cmd}\" is on cooldown. Please wait {(cooldownEnd - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds:F1} seconds.");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            // Check if command has reached its limit
            if (_commandLimits.ContainsKey(cmd))
            {
                if (!_commandUsages.ContainsKey(cmd))
                    _commandUsages[cmd] = 0;
                if (_commandUsages[cmd] >= _commandLimits[cmd])
                {
                    await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync($"Command \"{cmd}\" has reached its usage limit.");
                    return false;
                }
                _commandUsages[cmd]++;
            }

            // Execute the command
            await _commands[cmd](message, args);

            // Set cooldown
            if (_commandCooldowns.ContainsKey(cmd))
                _cooldowns[cmd] = DateTime.UtcNow;

            return true;
        }



       public async Task OnMessageReceived(SocketMessage message)
        {
            // Ignore messages from bots and system messages
            if (message.Author.IsBot || message.Author.IsWebhook) return;

       
            if (message.Content.StartsWith(_prefix))
            {
                // Remove the prefix from the message
                string command = message.Content.Substring(_prefix.Length);

                // Split the message into words
                string[] words = command.Split(' ');

                // The first word is the command
                string cmd = words[0];

                // The rest of the words are the arguments
                string[] args = words.Skip(1).ToArray();

                // Handle the command
                await ExecuteCommand(message, cmd, args);
            }

        }
   public void RegisterCommand(string command, Func<SocketMessage, string[], Task> action, int limit = 0, int cooldown = 0
)
        {
            _commands[command] = action;
            if (limit > 0)
                _commandLimits[command] = limit;
            if (cooldown > 0)
                _commandCooldowns[command] = cooldown;
        }
   RegisterCommand("play", async (message, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Length < 1)
                {
                    await bot.SendMessage(message.Channel.Id, "Usage: !play <url>");
                    return;
                }
                var url = args[0]; try
                {
                    bot._audioClient = await (message.Author as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel.ConnectAsync();
                    var stream = bot.CreateStream(url);
                    var output = bot._audioClient.CreatePCMStream(AudioApplication.Music);

                    await stream.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyToAsync(output);
                    await output.FlushAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                  //throw error
                    await bot.SendMessage(message.Channel.Id, "Error: " + ex.ToString());


                }


            });
            bot.RegisterCommand("stop", async (message, args) =>
            {
                if (bot._audioClient != null)
                {
                    await bot._audioClient.StopAsync();
     
                }
            });


ive tried googling everyone says thats its either that i have an old version of discord.net or nothing but I’m on the latest Version
i also made a some other functions to shorten the discord.net functions or make it simpler and the bot. blah blah is from a class where i have all that same stuff registered
and i don't know what to do?
any help related to it would be awesome
